# How to store dates in a portable way?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)
>   [What's the best way to manage dates across PHP, MySQL, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430736/whats-the-best-way-to-manage-dates-across-php-mysql-etc)

I want to store timestamps and then format them according to say, the user's timezone preference.

But I don't fully understand what the number returned by time() is.

Does it depend on the machine's timezone config?

Should I standarize it to UTC+0 before storing it?

If I use the same unix timestamp in different machines (different time zones) and format it with date(), will I have the same time (I don't mean the same format, but the same point in time)

Comment: Please see [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp/4812178#4812178)